# PHP How to add objet inside curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Tags: php, curl

I want to send an object (javascript object) in a  `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS)` function,
I tried some ways but couldnt find the right combination.
I tried the code bellow but I get the following error `syntex error unexpected {` in this line:
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, {`

how should I write the object?
what is the best pracrice for that in PHP

this is the object example:

```
{
    'Key': '',
    'Local': 'us',
    'UniqueId': '',
    'SuccessUrl': '',
    'CancelUrl': '',
    'CallbackUrl': '',
    'PaymentType': 'regular',
    'CreateInvoice': 'false',
    'AdditionalText': '',
    'ShowCart': 'true',
    'Installments': {
        Type: 'regular' , 
        MinQuantity: '1',
        MaxQuantity: '12'
    },
    'Customer': {
        'Email': 'someone@gmail.com',
        'Name': 'Demo Client' ,
        'PhoneNumber':  '031351315',
        'Attributes': {
            'HolderId':  'none' ,
            'Name':  'required' ,
            'PhoneNumber':  'required' ,
            'Email':  'optional'
        }
    },
   'CartItems': [{
        'Amount': '10.20',
        'Currency': 'usd',
        'Name': 'My Item1 Name',
        'Description': 'My Item description , comes below the name' , 
        'Quantity': 2 ,
        'Image': 'https://google.com' ,
        'IsTaxFree':  'false'
    }]
};
```

This is waht I tried:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://exampleurl.com/CreateSession");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, {
    \"Key\": \"1231231231231321321321321\",
    \"Local\": \"us\",
    \"UniqueId\": \"\",
    \"SuccessUrl\": \"\",
    \"CancelUrl\": \"\",
    \"CallbackUrl\": \"\",
    \"PaymentType\": \"regular\",
    \"CreateInvoice\": \"false\",
    \"AdditionalText\": \"\",
    \"ShowCart\": \"true\",
    \"Installments\": {
        Type: \"regular\" , 
        MinQuantity: \"1\",
        MaxQuantity: \"12\"
    },
    \"Customer\": {
        \"Email\": \"someone@gmail.com\",
        \"Name\": \"Demo Client\" ,
        \"PhoneNumber\":  \"21351135\",
        \"Attributes\": {
            \"HolderId\":  \"none\" ,
            \"Name\":  \"required\" ,
            \"PhoneNumber\":  \"required\" ,
            \"Email\":  \"optional\"
        }
    },
   \"CartItems\": [{
        \"Amount\": \"10.20\",
        \"Currency\": \"usd\",
        \"Name\": \"My Item1 Name\",
        \"Description\": \"My Item description , comes below the name\" , 
        \"Quantity\": 2 ,
        \"Image\": \"https://google.com.png\" ,
        \"IsTaxFree\":  \"false\"
    }]
});

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a string so should be enclosed in quotes:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{
    \"Key\": \"1231231231231321321321321\",
    \"Local\": \"us\",
    \"UniqueId\": \"\",
    \"SuccessUrl\": \"\",
    \"CancelUrl\": \"\",
    \"CallbackUrl\": \"\",
    \"PaymentType\": \"regular\",
    \"CreateInvoice\": \"false\",
    \"AdditionalText\": \"\",
    \"ShowCart\": \"true\",
    \"Installments\": {
        Type: \"regular\" ,
        MinQuantity: \"1\",
        MaxQuantity: \"12\"
    },
    \"Customer\": {
        \"Email\": \"someone@gmail.com\",
        \"Name\": \"Demo Client\" ,
        \"PhoneNumber\":  \"21351135\",
        \"Attributes\": {
            \"HolderId\":  \"none\" ,
            \"Name\":  \"required\" ,
            \"PhoneNumber\":  \"required\" ,
            \"Email\":  \"optional\"
        }
    },
   \"CartItems\": [{
        \"Amount\": \"10.20\",
        \"Currency\": \"usd\",
        \"Name\": \"My Item1 Name\",
        \"Description\": \"My Item description , comes below the name\" ,
        \"Quantity\": 2 ,
        \"Image\": \"https://google.com.png\" ,
        \"IsTaxFree\":  \"false\"
    }]
}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Store JSON data in one variable and simply post it.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

$jsonPost = `{
    "Key": "1231231231231321321321321",
    "Local": "us",
    "UniqueId": "",
    "SuccessUrl": "",
    "CancelUrl": "",
    "CallbackUrl": "",
    "PaymentType": "regular",
    "CreateInvoice": "false",
    "AdditionalText": "",
    "ShowCart": "true",
    "Installments": {
        Type: "regular" , 
        MinQuantity: "1",
        MaxQuantity: "12"
    },
    "Customer": {
        "Email": "someone@gmail.com",
        "Name": "Demo Client" ,
        "PhoneNumber":  "21351135",
        "Attributes": {
            "HolderId":  "none" ,
            "Name":  "required" ,
            "PhoneNumber":  "required" ,
            "Email":  "optional"
        }
    },
   "CartItems": [{
        "Amount": "10.20",
        "Currency": "usd",
        "Name": "My Item1 Name",
        "Description": "My Item description , comes below the name" , 
        "Quantity": 2 ,
        "Image": "https://google.com.png" ,
        "IsTaxFree":  "false"
    }]
}`;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://exampleurl.com/CreateSession");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonPost);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> syntex error unexpected {

because you missing `" "` or `' '`,

try this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{
    'Key': '',
    'Local': 'us',
    'UniqueId': '',
    'SuccessUrl': '',
    'CancelUrl': '',
    'CallbackUrl': '',
    'PaymentType': 'regular',
    'CreateInvoice': 'false',
    'AdditionalText': '',
    'ShowCart': 'true',
    'Installments': {
        Type: 'regular' , 
        MinQuantity: '1',
        MaxQuantity: '12'
    },
    'Customer': {
        'Email': 'someone@gmail.com',
        'Name': 'Demo Client' ,
        'PhoneNumber':  '031351315',
        'Attributes': {
            'HolderId':  'none' ,
            'Name':  'required' ,
            'PhoneNumber':  'required' ,
            'Email':  'optional'
        }
    },
   'CartItems': [{
        'Amount': '10.20',
        'Currency': 'usd',
        'Name': 'My Item1 Name',
        'Description': 'My Item description , comes below the name' , 
        'Quantity': 2 ,
        'Image': 'https://google.com' ,
        'IsTaxFree':  'false'
    }]
};");
```

i want to explain this but my english is bad, sorry.